# Global name error in python program

Tags: python, button, tkinter, global

I've got a code like that :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tkMessageBox as box
import time                                                     
from tkFileDialog   import askopenfilename,asksaveasfilename    
import pcapy                       
from impacket import ImpactDecoder, ImpactPacket                
import thread                                                   
import sys                                                      
import tkMessageBox      
from Tkinter import Tk, Text, BOTH, W, N, E, S, StringVar, END, Listbox
from ttk import Frame, Button, Label, Style


class Program(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)   

        self.parent = parent

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.parent.title("Wąchacz")
        self.style = Style()
        self.style.theme_use("default")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        devices = pcapy.findalldevs()
        acts = devices
        lb = Listbox(self)
        for i in acts:
            lb.insert(END, i)

        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(3, pad=7)
        self.rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(5, pad=7)

        lbl = Label(self, text="Wybierz interface:")
        lbl.grid(sticky=W, pady=4, padx=5)

        lb.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", self.onSelect)    

        lb.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, rowspan=4, 
            padx=5, sticky=E+W+S+N)

        self.var = StringVar()

        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(3, pad=7)
        self.rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(5, pad=7)


        abtn = Button(self, text="Start", command=self.start)
        abtn.grid( row=1, column=3)

        bbtn = Button(self, text="Stop", command=self.threadinterrupt)
        bbtn.grid(row=2, column=3, pady=4)

        cbtn = Button(self, text="Otwórz", command=self.OpenFile)
        cbtn.grid(row=3, column=3, pady=4)

        dbtn = Button(self, text="Zapisz", command=self.SaveFile)
        dbtn.grid(row=4, column=3, pady=4)

        ebtn = Button(self, text="O programie...", command=self.onAbout)
        ebtn.grid( row=5, column=3, pady=4)

        fbtn = Button(self, text="Zamknij", command=self.quitGui)
        fbtn.grid( row=5, column=0, pady=10)


    def start(self):
        try:
            thread.start_new_thread(eth_addr,())
        except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
               cleanup_stop_thread();
               sys.exit()   

    def threadinterrupt(self):
        thread.interrupt_main()


    def OpenFile(self):
        name = askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Pliki PCAP","*.pcap")],title="Otwórz plik pcap")

    def SaveFile(self):
        asksaveasfilename(filetypes=[("Pliki PCAP","*.pcap")],title="Zapisz plik pcap")                               

    def quitGui(self):
        answer = box.askquestion('wyjscie', "Napewno chcesz wyjść? ")
        if answer == 'yes':
            self.quit()


    def onAbout(self):
       box.showinfo("O programie", '''monitorowanie ruchu sieciowego''')

    def onSelect(self, val):

        interface1 = val.widget
        idx = interface1.curselection()
        value = interface1.get(idx)   

        self.var.set(value)


    def eth_addr(a) :
        b = "%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x" % (ord(a[0]) , ord(a[1]) , ord(a[2]), ord(a[3]), ord(a[4]) , ord(a[5]))
        return b
        global interface1
        interface1 =  str(var1.get())

        try:
            s = socket.socket( socket.AF_PACKET , socket.SOCK_RAW , socket.ntohs(0x0003))
        except socket.error, msg:
            print 'Kod błędu : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Wiadomość ' + msg[1]
            sys.exit()

        while True:
            packet = s.recvfrom(interface1 , 65536, True, 1000)

        packet = packet[0]

        eth_length = 14

        eth_header = packet[:eth_length]
        eth = unpack('!6s6sH' , eth_header)
        eth_protocol = socket.ntohs(eth[2])
        print 'Docelowy adres MAC : ' + eth_addr(packet[0:6]) + ' Źródłowy adres MAC : ' + eth_addr(packet[6:12]) + ' Protokół : ' + str(eth_protocol)

        if eth_protocol == 8 :
            ip_header = packet[eth_length:20+eth_length]

                iph = unpack('!BBHHHBBH4s4s' , ip_header)

                version_ihl = iph[0]
                version = version_ihl >> 4
                ihl = version_ihl & 0xF

                iph_length = ihl * 4

                ttl = iph[5]
                protocol = iph[6]
                s_addr = socket.inet_ntoa(iph[8]);
                d_addr = socket.inet_ntoa(iph[9]);

                print 'Wersja : ' + str(version) + ' Długość nagłówka IP : ' + str(ihl) + ' TTL : ' + str(ttl) + ' Protokół : ' + str(protocol) + ' Adres źródłowy : ' + str(s_addr) + ' Adres docelowy : ' + str(d_addr)


    if protocol == 6 :
        t = iph_length + eth_length
                tcp_header = packet[t:t+20]

                tcph = unpack('!HHLLBBHHH' , tcp_header)

                source_port = tcph[0]
                dest_port = tcph[1]
                sequence = tcph[2]
                acknowledgement = tcph[3]
                doff_reserved = tcph[4]
                tcph_length = doff_reserved >> 4

                print 'Port źródłowy : ' + str(source_port) + ' Port docelowy : ' + str(dest_port) + ' Numer sekwencji : ' + str(sequence) + ' Potwierdzenie : ' + str(acknowledgement) + ' Długość nagłówka TCP : ' + str(tcph_length)

                h_size = eth_length + iph_length + tcph_length * 4
                data_size = len(packet) - h_size
                data = packet[h_size:]

                print 'Dane : ' + data

    elif protocol == 1 :
                u = iph_length + eth_length
                icmph_length = 4
                icmp_header = packet[u:u+4]


                icmph = unpack('!BBH' , icmp_header)

                icmp_type = icmph[0]
                code = icmph[1]
                checksum = icmph[2]

                print 'Typ : ' + str(icmp_type) + ' Kod : ' + str(code) + ' Suma kontrolna : ' + str(checksum)

                h_size = eth_length + iph_length + icmph_length
                data_size = len(packet) - h_size


                data = packet[h_size:]

                print 'Dane : ' + data

    elif protocol == 17 :
                u = iph_length + eth_length
                udph_length = 8
                udp_header = packet[u:u+8]


                udph = unpack('!HHHH' , udp_header)

                source_port = udph[0]
                dest_port = udph[1]
                length = udph[2]
                checksum = udph[3]

                print 'Port źródłowy : ' + str(source_port) + ' Port docelowy : ' + str(dest_port) + ' Długość : ' + str(length) + ' Suma kontrolna : ' + str(checksum)

                h_size = eth_length + iph_length + udph_length
                data_size = len(packet) - h_size


                data = packet[h_size:]

                print 'Dane : ' + data

    else :
                print 'Protokół inny niż TCP/UDP/ICMP'

        print


def main():

    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("350x300+300+300")
    app = Program(root)
    root.mainloop()  




if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

but after pushing start button I've got a traceback :

> Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1489, in **call**
>       return self.func(*args)   File "example.py", line 80, in start
>       thread.start_new_thread(eth_addr,()) NameError: global name 'eth_addr' is not defined

can anybody help me with this global name problem ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the guidelines about how to ask a good question, including importantly [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Is it possible that you meant `self.eth_addr`?

Comment: Sure, I just found it out, thanks !

Have you any idea what's about an error now :
Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Program.eth_addr of <__main__.Program instance at 0x7fc040536170>>
TypeError: eth_addr() takes no arguments (1 given)
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `start` method, you're referring to a variable called `eth_addr`, which isn't defined anywhere. It's also exactly what your error message is telling you. (you're probably looking for `self.eth_addr`)

(in addition, stop using `start_new_thread` -- it's a low-level primitive that should never be called directly. Use `threading.Thread` objects instead.)

Comment: Actually, `eth_addr` is the name of a function that the OP defined inside the `Program` class.

Comment: ...Which means that as a *variable* (which is how it's used), it isn't defined anywhere. The `eth_addr` method in the `Program` class should be referred with `self.eth_addr` from other methods of that class.

Comment: @iCodez sure, and I made something like this several times and always it worked but not now.

Comment: @ Max Noel thanks !
I've got one more problem now, have You any idea what's about an error : Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Program.eth_addr of <__main__.Program instance at 0x7fc040536170>> TypeError: eth_addr() takes no arguments (1 given) ?

Comment: That's probably because `eth_addr`, like all instance methods, should take `self` as its first argument. It looks like you should read a Python tutorial: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html